# Closing lid causes image to reset on external screen

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, cursor, lid

I have been attaching my laptop to my TV for streaming (of things I can't get on my TV). I set the laptop such that I can close the lid and not put it to sleep.

The problem is, when I close the lid on my laptop, the cursor lights up right in the center of the screen. This is no good for watching streaming video. Is there a way that I can make the cursor remain where it was when I closed the lid (which is always off of the screen)?

I realize I can use an external mouse to move the cursor out of the way, but this seems like a step I shouldn't have to do!

I am using an Acer Aspire 3 laptop with Windows 10.  I also have a Toshiba laptop with Windows 10 on which I can close the lid, the internal monitor goes off, but the image on the TV remains constant. Seems there has to be a reason/setting that is different between the two.

Comment: Are both screens enabled before closing the lid? Or just the external one?

Comment: Shut lid partially only? Whats likely happening is when the lid is shut Windows disconnects the internal LCD (laptop screen) hence the flash as it sets up the TV as the only screen & moves the mouse cursor over there TRYING to be convenient. An external mouse seems like an easy fix. Harder fix: remove magnet that tells Windows lid is shut. Can't explain why it doesn't happen on Toshiba, maybe because a different graphics card driver setup?

Comment: gronostaj - Both screens are enabled (duplicated) until the lid closes.

Answer (score 1):

Press `Win`+`P` until "Second screen only" is selected before closing the lid. Press `Win`+`P` until one of the other options (whichever you desire) is selected when you want to use the laptop screen again.

Comment: I'll have to give that a try!!! Sounds like that might work! How do I then get the screen back when I reopen the laptop?

Comment: @Jim Hold `Win`, press `P` twice, release `Win`. This will duplicate your screen as you had it before.

Comment: @Jim did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry.....I haven't had the opportunity to check it out. I haven't streamed anything in a couple weeks. I'll let you know though. Thanks!!!